# How to work with an objectAtIndex in a for function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This function works well, but it always returns the same value because I don't know how to work with the objectatindex. And this:

```
NSLog (@"Object at index %d is: %@", i, [appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex: i]);
```

Returns this:

```
2011-03-20 14:38:07.365 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 0 is: <Animals: 0x6151a20>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.367 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 1 is: <Animals: 0x6151ba0>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.368 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 2 is: <Animals: 0x6151d20>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.371 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 3 is: <Animals: 0x6151e90>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.374 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 4 is: <Animals: 0x6151ff0>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.375 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 5 is: <Animals: 0x6152180>
```

This is my full code:  I actually have to combine the things in the for function.

```
int i = 0;
int count;

TutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Animals *aAnimal = (Animals *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:i];

count = [appDelegate.animals count];


for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // returns the right value, but always the same because no objectAtIndex
    NSLog(@"%@",aAnimal.animalName);


    NSLog (@"Object at index %d is: %@", 
           i, [appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex: i]);




}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it always returns the same value"? Each line prints a different object...

Comment: what code do you have in your appDelegate

Comment: The NSLog(@"%@",aAnimal.animalName); returns always the same value, the other NSLog is fine but does actually have to print out what the first nslog prints out, but that NSLog always prints out the same value of course. Because I do not use the objectAtIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Animals* nextAnimal = (Animals*)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex: i];
    NSLog (@"Object at index %d is: %@", 
           i, nextAnimal.animalName);
}
```

The reason you're seeing stuff like:

```
1-03-20 14:38:07.365 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 0 is: <Animals: 0x6151a20>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.367 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 1 is: <Animals: 0x6151ba0>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.368 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 2 is: <Animals: 0x6151d20>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.371 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 3 is: <Animals: 0x6151e90>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.374 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 4 is: <Animals: 0x6151ff0>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.375 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 5 is: <Animals: 0x6152180>
```

...is because you're logging the entire object, and not just the name.  But you can see that a different object is indeed being returned each time by looking at the memory address of each one (the part that looks like `0x615....`).

Comment: This code works great, although you forgot the close your second line ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing actually wrong with your code - so I'm not sure what you're tying to do. You're printing out the actual pointer to the console, so you're seeing the memory locations of each object in the array.

```
2011-03-20 14:38:07.365 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 0 is: <Animals: 0x6151a20>
2011-03-20 14:38:07.367 Tutorial[5063:207] Object at index 1 is: <Animals: 0x6151ba0>
```

Do you see how the two objects are different? Object 0 is located at 0x615***a20***, and Object 1 is located at 0x6151***ba0***. What you want is to print out something *useful* from that object, which I can't really give you any help on as I don't know what your custom object containts.

It's a bit unclear what's going on in your code, but if you have an array (and I assume, since you're using `objectAtIndex:`, you do), it's much better to iterate through it as follows:

```
for (id object in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"I am: %@", [object description]);
}
```

That syntax is Apple's recommended way to iterate through an NSArray. It adds more protection against the array changing while you're iterating through it.

Comment: Thank you! Your information is very straightforward! Can you tell me what to fill in in the (id object in myArray) for some reason I doesn't work,the description is this a key of my array or something standard by Apple? Thanx!

Comment: ...you should put in the array you want to iterate through. So I guess `appDelegate.animals`. `description` is part of `NSObject`, so hopefully your object will respond to it (I assume it's an NSObject subclass).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the NSLog description to be more informative, override -description in your class. for example

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    NSString *description = [super description];
    description = [description stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@ %@", self.name, self.age];
    return description;
}
```

Then, when NSLog will call the Animal's description method, you'll see whatever properties you choose to print out.